# Matplotlib prints wrong size if entire notebook rerun, but if cell is run individually, it prints 10 x 3

Tags: python, matplotlib

Jupyter Notebooks. Python 3.10.1

Issue: Graph size is about an 8x8 when the entire notebook is executed using the 'Restart Kernel, re-run entire notebook' but however, when you go to the individual cell and run it, it prints at the correct 10x3 size.

**This is the first plot that I created on this notebook. Does anybody have an idea as to why the figure size may differ based on how the cell is run?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

ax = result.plot(color='#26379f', marker = ".")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] =  10, 3
ax.set_xticks(range(len(result)))
ax.set_xticklabels(["%s-%02d" % item for item in result.index.tolist()],
rotation=45, ha='center', color='#26379f')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#26379f')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#26379f')
plt.xlabel('Year-Month', color='#26379f')
plt.ylabel('Revenue Generated ($)', color='#26379f')
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Arial"
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 11
plt.title("Total Revenue Generated per Month")
plt.savefig('revenue_timeseries.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi=200)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: What is `result` in `ax = result.plot(color='#26379f', marker = ".")`? Are you sure none of the operations in this snippet change the value of that variable/object?

Comment: result is a dataframe with a multi-index 'Year and Month'. `result = datatime_dates.groupby([datatime_dates['Date'].dt.year, datatime_dates['Date'].dt.month]).agg({'Amount':sum})`

Comment: Did you try calling `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] =  10, 3` before `ax = result.plot(color='#26379f', marker = ".")`?

Comment: I did not! Just changed that and it looks like it fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Wait, lemme make a proper response, so I can get rep :D

Answer (score 2):

Calling `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] =  10, 3` before `ax = result.plot(color='#26379f', marker = ".")` should fix it, because the former changes a kind-of global parameter for `matplotlib` before you instantiate the axis object.

I think a cleaner way of doing this is:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))

# Some plotting of your things using ax.plot() or ax.scatter()

ax.set_xticks(range(len(result)))
ax.set_xticklabels(["%s-%02d" % item for item in result.index.tolist()],
rotation=45, ha='center', color='#26379f')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#26379f')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#26379f')
ax.set_xlabel('Year-Month', color='#26379f')
ax.set_ylabel('Revenue Generated ($)', color='#26379f')
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Arial"
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 11
ax.set_title("Total Revenue Generated per Month")
ax.savefig('revenue_timeseries.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', dpi=200)

# These two below might be redundant
plt.show()  
plt.close()
```

This way you don't mix the matlab-like interface with the object-oriented interface. I think `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Arial"` and `plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 11` can also be replaced with calls to `ax`, but I don't remember that off the top of my head.

Note that some `plt.foo()` functions change to `ax.set_foo()` methods.